# thousand separator for bitrates in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

how can i add a comma to the bitrate variable in windows batch? (without using powershell)

examples:

2 000 kb/s => 2,000 kb/s      (replace the space with a comma)

876 kb/s => 876 kb/s          (no change)

10.1 MB/s => 10.1 MB/s        (no change)

is it possible to do it in a simple 1 or 2-liner?

also, the bitrates varies from each video. it is not fixed.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a "simple 1 or 2 liner" solution that works on numbers (not *bitrates*) upto 9 digits each. It also offers the additional feature of align (right justify) the converted numbers. If you want not the alignment, just eliminate the spaces (via a `for` command, for example).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize data, just once
set "c = " & for /L %%i in (0,1,9) do set "c%%i=,"

rem Generate a series of test numbers between 1 and 9 digits, with two optional decimals
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
   set "num=!random!!random!"
   for %%d in (!random:~-1!) do if %%d gtr 0 set "num=!num:~0,%%d!"
   if !random:~-1! geq 5 set "num=!num!.!random:~-2!"
   call :insertCommas !num!
)
goto :EOF

:insertCommas num

for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in ("%1") do set "int=        %%a" & if "%%b" equ "" (set "frc=   ") else set "frc=.%%b"
echo %int:~-9%%frc%  =  %int:~-9,3%!c%int:~-7,1%!%int:~-6,3%!c%int:~-4,1%!%int:~-3%%frc%
exit /B
```

Output example:

```
     1719     =        1,719
155292712     =  155,292,712
  3269828.90  =    3,269,828.90
     1300     =        1,300
254112572.84  =  254,112,572.84
        1.98  =            1.98
   269462     =      269,462
     1637     =        1,637
       13     =           13
   153851.04  =      153,851.04
```

**EDIT 2021/12/13:** *New method as requested by comment*

It seems the purpose of this question was misunderstood...

The new code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "bitrate=%%a"
   set "bitrate=!bitrate: =,!"
   echo !bitrate:~0,-5! !bitrate:~-4!
)
```

Sample input data:

```
2 000 kb/s
876 kb/s
10.1 MB/s
```

Output:

```
2,000 kb/s
876 kb/s
10.1 MB/s
```

Comment: thanks, but the number is "2 000" and not "2000". there's a space, so i am not sure how to do it

Comment: I see... You were not clear enough about your requirement! (You want not to "*add* a comma" and certainly powershell can not directly do this either). See the edit in my answer; if this is not what you want, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70323128/edit) and insert a *sample file* of the input data that I can copy, and the desired output from such an input.

Comment: So?... My new solution works?